# How to get row of element in cell by javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a simple table like this

```
<table id="tempTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_01">
            <td>
                <button onclick="btnclick(this);" >Save Row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row_02">
            <td>
                <button onclick="btnclick(this);" >Save Row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

function btnclick(e) {
    var currentRow = $(e).parent().parent();
    alert(currentRow.id);
}
```

I want to determine which row where the button clicked was placed. So I use some jquery method in btnclick() as you see abow. But sometime I don't know how deep level the button was placed in row (), so Im looking for a way to get an ancestor by tag `<tr>` of a element.

Anybody help me, thanks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

```
function btnclick(e) {
    var currentRow = $(e).closest('tr');
    alert(currentRow.id);
}
```

The `closest()` function will return the closest ancestor referenced by its selector.  In this case the selector is simple a `<tr>` element.

Taken from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) :

> ### .closest( selector )
>
> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and  progressing up through the DOM tree.

---

A better method *could* be used if you change your HTML a little bit.  If you placed the same class on each of your buttons.
Eg :

```
<td>
  <button class="myBtnClass" >Save Row</button>
</td>
```

Then your jQuery would look like this :

```
$(".myBtnClass").on('click',function(){
    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    alert(currentRow.attr('id'));
});
```

This function will capture a click on **any** element with the `.myBtnClass` class.

Comment: Thanks @TJ. - hopefully the OP feels the same way :)

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery way is:

```
$('#tempTable').find('button').click(function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

how about using closest

```
function btnclick(e) {
    var currentRow = $(e).closest('tr');
    alert(currentRow.id);
}
```